DBMS returning multiple # symbol as value when I enter a sql query
DBMS seems to show me values that are replaced with # symbol. Below would be my record and the records that i was planning to retrive data from. The picture attached would be output from DBMS.
ACCEPT Worker_ID PROMPT 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR WORKER ID HERE: '

COLUMN Worker_ID FORMAT A4
COLUMN W_First_Name FORMAT A10
COLUMN W_Last_Name FORMAT A20
COLUMN W_Age FORMAT A2
COLUMN Salary FORMAT A10
COLUMN section_ID FORMAT A2
COLUMN section_Name FORMAT A12

TTITLE CENTER 'Worker's Basic Information & His/Her Section' SKIP 2；
SELECT w.Worker_ID, w.W_First_Name, w.W_Last_Name, w.W_Age, w.Salary, s.section_ID, s.section_Name
FROM Worker w JOIN Section s ON （w.Section_ID = s.section_ID）
WHERE w.Worker_ID = '&Worker_ID';


insert into Worker (Worker_ID, section_ID, W_First_Name, W_Last_Name,
W_Gender, W_Age, Date_of_Employment, W_Email, W_Phone_Num, Salary)
values (1152, 1, 'Sidoney', 'Teenan', 'F', 38, '08-Feb-2014',
'steenan0@go.com', 601797286126, 29721);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES(1, 'Pilot', 'Pilots ensure safe flights,
navigate, and communicate.');



sqlplus shows ## when it can't fit the value in the column space allotted in the client. You can enlarge that column size by using the sqlplus command col: col section_name format a50, col w_age format a30, etc.. whatever you need. This is one reason why sqlplus isn't a great client. It's better suited to scripting. Consult sqlplus docs for more info.

Using FORMAT A2 for a numeric column seems odd anyway; you probably meant FORMAT 999?

@AlexPoole I've tried changing all numerical columns to format 999 but it still doesnt seem to affect anything

@PaulW sorry but would u mind to elaborate further, apologies as im new to the language

your column format needs to be as large as your largest value to not see ###. Also be sure the columns in the table aren't using the CHAR datatype with a large size. If they do, try RTRIM to remove trailing spaces, and if it's your table, rebuild it with varchar2 and not char.  For further work in SQLPlus you can consult the docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/index.html

@zuohao - I would have thought 999 (or even 99) would do for w_age (though it'll add a leading space to allow for the +/- sign); other numbers will be bigger, so for those you need as many 9s as you could have digits for each column - see the linked question. The heading format implies they are numbers not strings, so use the numeric format elements. (You could also explicitly format them as strings with to_char() if you prefer.)

Check if there is some sort of security setting implemented on this DB. Generally, #s are shown for two scenarios;

If the values provided that larger than the column's specified format limit.
If there is a privacy setting that masks the values in the output (for example, SSN)

I don't think its option 1 in your case. But maybe dig deeper into the DB security settings if there are any privacy settings incorporated for the IDs, salary, age fields etc.

Hi, thank for the answers, would u mind to explain what db security settings mean, sorry for the extra trouble as im completely new to database

It isn't security settings, it's the invalid FORMAT being used...
